# Как построить график по нескольким столбцам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, визуализация

Как построить график по нескольким столбцам DataFrame?

Например `df.columns[10:]`.

По этому примеру - не работает:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(df.columns[10:])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [встроенными в Pandas средствами визуализации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 10:].plot(legend=False)
```

Comment: @mosag4, приведите в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить или эскиз

Comment: @mosag4, я не понял чего вы хотите, но все на самом деле очень просто - просто прочтите [документацию](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) ;)

Comment: @mosag4, я отклонил вашу правку моего ответа - не надо вандализировать чужие ответы) Все детали относящиеся к вопросу указывайте в вопросе...